# User-defined conversion function and casting to reference

Tags: c++, type-conversion

I am encountering a compilation error for the following code:

```
class SymbolGroup
{
  std::string d_;

public:
  SymbolGroup(std::string a):d_(a){}

  // explicit operator const std::string&() const { return d_;} // compiles
  explicit operator std::string() const { return d_;} // Does not compile
};

inline
bool operator==(const SymbolGroup& lhs, const SymbolGroup& rhs)
{
  return static_cast<const std::string&>(lhs) ==
    static_cast<const std::string&>(rhs);
}

int main(){

  SymbolGroup a("hello");
  SymbolGroup b("hello");

  if (a==b)
    std::cout << "they are the same\n";

  return 0;
}
```

Without the 'const' and '&' in the user-defined type conversion line, it does not compile in g++ (4.8) with --std=c++11 flag:

> error: invalid initialization of reference of type ‘std::string& {aka
>   std::basic_string&}’ from expression of type ‘const string {aka
>   const std::basic_string}’    explicit operator std::string&()
>   const { return d_;}

The code compiles on Clang both ways. Which compiler is correct? Should this code compile with `operator std::string()`?

Comment: I get [no compilation error](http://cpp.sh/6wbj)

Comment: @CoryKramer Did you compile using the version without 'const' and '&' ?

Comment: Just FYI - if you're asking questions about code not compiling, it's better to write the example as code that doesn't compile so that people can just quickly copy and paste.

Comment: Ok after what seems like my 10th attempt at answering this question, I finally got it right. Probably.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**UPDATE** My previous answer was exactly wrong. Apologies! tldr; clang is correct to accept the code, gcc is incorrect to reject it.

---

First, from [expr.static.cast]:

> An expression e can be explicitly converted to a type T using a static_cast of the form `static_cast<T>(e)`
>   if the declaration `T t(e)`; is well-formed, for some invented temporary variable t (8.5).

So effectively we're trying to direct-initialize an object of type `std::string const&` explicitly from an object of type `SymbolGroup const&`. There is a section specifically on initializing references by a conversion function: "Initialization by conversion function for direct reference binding" [over.match.ref]:

> Under the conditions specified in 8.5.3, a reference can be bound directly to a glvalue or class prvalue that is
>   the result of applying a conversion function to an initializer expression. Overload resolution is used to select
>   the conversion function to be invoked. Assuming that “*cv1* T” is the underlying type of the reference being
>   initialized, and “*cv* S” is the type of the initializer expression, with S a class type, the candidate functions
>   are selected as follows:
>
> — The conversion functions of S and its base classes are considered. Those non-explicit conversion
>   functions that [...] are candidate functions. For direct-initialization, those explicit
>   conversion functions that are not hidden within S and yield type “lvalue reference to *cv2* T2” or “*cv2*
>   T2” or “rvalue reference to *cv2* T2”, respectively, where T2 is the same type as T or can be converted
>   to type T with a qualification conversion (4.4), are also candidate functions.

The first part doesn't apply since our conversion function is `explicit`, so I omitted it. The second part does. We have *cv1* T is `const std::string`, so our conversion function to `std::string` is a candidate function because `std::string` can be converted to `const std::string` with a qualification conversion.

---

gcc is wrong here, and I filed [bug 66893](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=66893), confirmed by our very own C++ expert and all around good guy [Jonathan Wakely](https://stackoverflow.com/users/981959/jonathan-wakely) as well as the head Clang developer and C++ standard editor Richard Smith (after I thoroughly embarrassed myself filing a Clang bug).

Answer (score 1):

Well sir, the answer i pretty straightforward. Instead of casting to const reference in return like this:

```
return static_cast<const std::string&>(lhs) == static_cast<const std::string&>(rhs);
```

Cast your type to `std::string`:

```
return static_cast<std::string>(lhs) == static_cast<std::string>(rhs);
```

And enjoy working code :)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question. Furthermore, OP wants to avoid copying strings.

Comment: The thing is `(const std::string&)(lhs) == (const std::string&)(rhs);` compiles and `static_cast<const std::string&>(lhs) == static_cast<const std::string&>(rhs);` does not. Is this difference stated in standard?

Comment: AFAIK using c-style cast is dangerous in c++, because it makes compiler choose way of cast by itself. So it can simultaneously perform static, const nad reinterpret cast. Perhaps in your example it uses static and const cast together

Comment: @bartop I think the question is whether this behavior is specified in standard or gcc bug since clang compiles code with static_cast.